# Passing member functions as template parameters in D

Tags: d

I created a class which implements the Sieve of Atkin to find primes.  The class stores the results and provides an "isPrime" method.  I would like to also add a range which allows you to iterate over the primes.  I was thinking of something like this:

```
@property auto iter() { return filter!(this.isPrime)(iota(2, max, 1)); }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
Error: function primes.primes.isPrime (ulong i) is not callable using argument types ()
Error: expected 1 function arguments, not 0
```

without the "this" I get

```
Error: this for isPrime needs to be type primes not type Result
```

Is there any way to pass a member function as a template argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use methods (delegates) for template parameters, because they need a context, which is not known at compile-time.

You can either make `isPrime` a static method or free function (then remove `this.` and your code will work), or (if the method is not static on purpose), use an anonymous delegate literal:

```or-tag-here
@property auto iter() { return filter!((x) { return isPrime(x); })(iota(2, max, 1)); }
```

In 2.058 you'll be able to write:

```or-tag-here
@property auto iter() { return filter!(x => isPrime(x))(iota(2, max, 1)); }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the *address* of the function otherwise the compiler thinks you want to call the function with 0 args and then pass the result

```
@property auto iter() { return filter!(&isPrime)(iota(2, max, 1)); }
```